# How to stop receiving inputs on edit mode

Tags: javascript, angular, input, onchange

I got a very simple case of a form with an `@Input elements: Observable<Student[]>` which is being updated every 2 seconds, hence triggers the `onChanges` of my form component which cause unexpected behaviours, such as reseting of `<input>` values, selected `<select>`'s `<option>`, etc..

The approach I've taken for such case is defining the component on Edit-mode and View-mode and while on Edit-mode unsubscribing from the Observable Input and on View-mode resubscribing.

Is there a more elegant, maybe built-in `Angular 2`, way to handle such cases?

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify change detection in your angular component to `OnPush` to prevent unnecessary overriding of your local changes.

```
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Or even you can go further and track changes manually only when you need them:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.inputSubject.subscribe((data) => {
    this.inputService.update(data);
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  })
 }
}
```